# Use cross-reference in Mac Notes

Tags: notes.app

I used to use personal WIKIs to organize personal info, but due to increasingly strong browser security control and poor mobile support, I switched to Mac/iOS Notes and find it very comfortable to work with, except for one quirk:

I can't find a way to cross-reference info like WIKI does.

Is there a workaround?